# ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 20 and 320 for 'loss) with input shapes: [1,320,320,20,12], [1,320,320,12]

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

So I'm working in medical images which each sample and ground truth has shape 320,320,20 where 20 is the number of slice. the problem is that y_true and y_pred does not match should I reshape or do another task. any suggestion will be appreciate.

```
Y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(Y_train, num_classes=12, dtype=np.uint8)
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((320, 320,20))
smooth = 1.

s = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x / 255)(inputs)
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(
    s)  # Kernelsize : start with some weights initial value
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c1)
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(
    c1)  # Kernelsize : start with some weights initial value
p1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2))(c1)

c2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(
    p1)  # Kernelsize : start with some weights initial value
c2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c2)
c2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(
    c2)  # Kernelsize : start with some weights initial value
p2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2))(c2)

c3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(
    p2)  # Kernelsize : start with some weights initial value
c3 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c3)
c3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(
    c3)  # Kernelsize : start with some weights initial value
p3 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2))(c3)

c4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(
    p3)  # Kernelsize : start with some weights initial value
c4 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c4)
c4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(
    c4)  # Kernelsize : start with some weights initial value
p4 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2))(c4)

c5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(
    p4)  # Kernelsize : start with some weights initial value
c5 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c5)
c5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(
    c5)  # Kernelsize : start wi

u6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c5)
u6 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u6, c4])
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u6)
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c6)
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c6)

u7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c6)
u7 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u7, c3])
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (2, 2), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u7)
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c7)
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c7)

u8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c7)
u8 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u8, c2])
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (2, 2), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u8)
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c8)
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c8)

u9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(16, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c8)
u9 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u9, c1], axis=3)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u9)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c9)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c9)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(12, (1, 1), activation='softmax')(c9)
#op  = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((82944,12))(outputs)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
```

when I try to fit the model I get this error:

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 20 and 320 for 'loss/conv2d_18_loss/mul' (op: 'Mul') with input shapes: [1,320,320,20,12], [1,320,320,12].
```

Summary

Model: "model"

---

```
________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 320, 320, 20 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda (Lambda)                 (None, 320, 320, 20) 0           input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)                 (None, 320, 320, 16) 2896        lambda[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)               (None, 320, 320, 16) 0           conv2d[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 320, 320, 16) 2320        dropout[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 160, 160, 16) 0           conv2d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)               (None, 160, 160, 32) 4640        max_pooling2d[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)             (None, 160, 160, 32) 0           conv2d_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)               (None, 160, 160, 32) 9248        dropout_1[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 80, 80, 32)   0           conv2d_3[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)               (None, 80, 80, 64)   18496       max_pooling2d_1[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)             (None, 80, 80, 64)   0           conv2d_4[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)               (None, 80, 80, 64)   36928       dropout_2[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 40, 40, 64)   0           conv2d_5[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)               (None, 40, 40, 128)  73856       max_pooling2d_2[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)             (None, 40, 40, 128)  0           conv2d_6[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)               (None, 40, 40, 128)  147584      dropout_3[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 20, 20, 128)  0           conv2d_7[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)               (None, 20, 20, 256)  295168      max_pooling2d_3[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)             (None, 20, 20, 256)  0           conv2d_8[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)               (None, 20, 20, 256)  590080      dropout_4[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose (Conv2DTranspo (None, 40, 40, 128)  131200      conv2d_9[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, 40, 40, 256)  0           conv2d_transpose[0][0]           
                                                                 conv2d_7[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)              (None, 40, 40, 128)  295040      concatenate[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_5 (Dropout)             (None, 40, 40, 128)  0           conv2d_10[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_11 (Conv2D)              (None, 40, 40, 128)  147584      dropout_5[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_1 (Conv2DTrans (None, 80, 80, 64)   32832       conv2d_11[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 80, 80, 128)  0           conv2d_transpose_1[0][0]         
                                                                 conv2d_5[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_12 (Conv2D)              (None, 80, 80, 64)   32832       concatenate_1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_6 (Dropout)             (None, 80, 80, 64)   0           conv2d_12[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_13 (Conv2D)              (None, 80, 80, 64)   36928       dropout_6[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_2 (Conv2DTrans (None, 160, 160, 32) 8224        conv2d_13[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_2 (Concatenate)     (None, 160, 160, 64) 0           conv2d_transpose_2[0][0]         
                                                                 conv2d_3[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_14 (Conv2D)              (None, 160, 160, 32) 8224        concatenate_2[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_7 (Dropout)             (None, 160, 160, 32) 0           conv2d_14[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_15 (Conv2D)              (None, 160, 160, 32) 9248        dropout_7[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_3 (Conv2DTrans (None, 320, 320, 16) 2064        conv2d_15[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_3 (Concatenate)     (None, 320, 320, 32) 0           conv2d_transpose_3[0][0]         
                                                                 conv2d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_16 (Conv2D)              (None, 320, 320, 16) 4624        concatenate_3[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_8 (Dropout)             (None, 320, 320, 16) 0           conv2d_16[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_17 (Conv2D)              (None, 320, 320, 16) 2320        dropout_8[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_18 (Conv2D)              (None, 320, 320, 12) 204         conv2d_17[0][0]                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 1,892,540
Trainable params: 1,892,540
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Since I'm just testing I added only 2 image for sample and 2 for GT:

```
X-train shape: (2, 320, 320, 20)
X-train max: 255
X-train min: 0
X-train average: 45.08897802734375
Y-train shape: (2, 320, 320, 20)
Y-train max: 11
Y-train min: 0
Y-train average: 0.84169189453125
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you posted the output of `model.summary()`

Comment: thanks for replay, Sure

Comment: @BlackBear I add it

Comment: What are you trying to do? given an input of shape (320, 320, 20), you want to have a target map of (320, 320) where each pixel belongs to one of the 12 classes?.

Comment: @BashirKazimi Exactly I have 12 output class so maybe my output should be 320x320x20x12?

Comment: @BashirKazimi any idea  pls

Comment: @BlackBear any idea pls

Comment: So you have 20 slices of size 320x320, and you want to classify each pixel of each slice in 12 classes? Then yes the output should be 320x320x20x12

Comment: @BlackBear Thank's again, Please how can I change my output from 320x320x12 to 320x320x20x12

Comment: I think you should get a better understanding of your inputs and outputs. If you originally have an output of shape (320,320,20) similar to your input, you cannot solve your problem with your current model. Can you print out your Xtrain and Ytrain's shapes and maximum, minimum, and average values before calling the to_catgorical function?

Comment: @BashirKazimi I added those value to my modified post. so even if I change my output to  (320,320,20,12) it should not work?

Comment: You cannot change your output to (320,320,20,12) using 2D convolutions. I am not really sure, but either I am not understanding your task or you need to change your method. Sorry, good luck :)

Comment: @BashirKazimi it's okey thank you :)